# Python API for generating shareable links for each item in a folder in OneDrive

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am looking for automating some mandane workflow at my office here. For which I would like to use the OneDrive API for python.

[image]

Assuming I have a list of files in onedrive. I would like to get the list of items in a folder from my OneDrive and would also like to generate the shareable link for each of those items using Python.

[image]

**Is there an API with which I can achieve the same ?**

Looking forward for some answers

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with OneDrive through [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-beta).
The API you're looking for is the [CreateLink API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp), you can use it to generate a link for each item or the whole folder I believe.

There is no Microsoft Graph SDK for python as far as I know, which means you will have to do the calls manually including [acquiring the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta).